# Mechanics question I don't understand solution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

A simple top consists of a heavy circular disc of mass m and radius a mounted at the center of a thin rod of mass $\frac{m}{2}$ and length a. If the top is set spinning at given rate S, and with the axis at angle of 45 degrees with vertical, there are two possible values of the precession rate $\dot{\phi}$ such that the top precesses steadily at a constant rate of $\theta = 45$.

In my professor solution I don't know why he wrote

$I_{cm,disk} = \frac{ma^2}{4} + \frac{ma^2}{4}$

How come is the rotation of the disk not in the z-axis even and is only in the x-y plane ?

Comment: A rotation is always _around_ an axis, never _in the plane_. The inertial moment of a disc and a rod can be found in Wikipedia and can be added up to give the inertial moment of the top.

Comment: Is $\theta$ an angle or an angular velocity?

Comment: theta is the angle